# How to resolve the ORA01722 error from rownum function

Tags: sql, oracle

Getting the below error when I query
ORA-01722:invalid identifier

```
select * 
from [table_name] 
where rownum<5;
```

Comment: What is `[table_name]`? Does it exist? Are you in the right database? Does it have a `rownum` column? Show enough info for readers to answer your question please

Comment: there is a table_name that is present in the database..say for example employee and there is no specific column rownum in the table..it is psuedocolumn

Comment: Are you given table name or like  [table_name] only execute the query.. please give the actual table name and run the query once..I guess you'll get your expected output.. Thanks..!!

Comment: Did you get "invalid identifier" ? I'm not sure, but i think this error code belongs to "invalid number".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to use SQL Server syntax in Oracle. To quote identifiers in Oracle use double quotes not brackets.

```
SELECT *
       FROM "table_name"
       WHERE rownum < 5;
```

But this will only work if the table has bee created with a lower case name explicitly, also using quotes. Chances are it wasn't and therefore you want not to use any quoting at all.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table_name
       WHERE rownum < 5;
```